# What would have happened if Finn had succeeded?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

Near the end of The Last Jedi, we see Finn

> making a kamikaze run into the First Order's laser battering ram, when Rose intercepts him, knocking both their speeders to the ground on the side, in front of a row of AT-ATs.
>
>
>  (After which the First Order completely ignores them and Finn manages to *drag Rose by foot* all the way back to the Resistance base before the First Order has made any significant progress!)
>
>
>  What would have happened if Finn had completed his attack?  Would he have been able to stop the battering ram, or was he making a foolish sacrifice?
>
>
>  To me it looked like he and his ship would be mostly melted before reaching the target.  But at the same time, he seemed adamant that he could make a difference to the battle.  I wonder which is true.

Comment: My impression is that it would be like a fly hitting the windshield of your car, so it would be somewhat pointless.

Comment: The sales would've dropped by 1.4% in Nigeria and England, home countries of Finn. That's why they didn't do it. Storywise, a confusing action scene would've happened

Answer (score 4):

In theory, the scrap metal from the broken down speeder could theoretically jam the turbine(?) of the ram. But the way they depicted the heat level even that far from the ram, the metal would probably just have melted before doing anything.